# Ajax Authentication without DoS attack possible

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I have a Web Service that I used it to Authenticate Users:

```
public bool ValidateUser(string username, string password,bool rememberMe)
    {
        if(Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, rememberMe);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And I  call it from client via jQuery:

```
function validateUser() {

            var username = $('#<%=UserName.ClientID %>').val();
            var pass =$('#<%=Password.ClientID %>').val();
                            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Services/LoginService.asmx/ValidateUser",
                data: "{'username ':'" + username + "','password':'" + pass + "','rememberMe':'" + $('#<%=chbRememberMe.ClientID %>').attr('checked') + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data, status) { OnSuccessLogin(data, status); },
                error: OnErrorLogin
            });
        }
```

now I think it's open to denial-of-service attacks and a hacker can call the web service many times to slow down the server.

Is there a way to secure it?

Comment: Please clearify if you are asking about a SYN-Flood on TCP level (the question title suggest this) or if you are asking about an DoS on service level.

Comment: I mean DoS on service and I changed the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a good way:

[Prevent Denial of Service (DOS) attacks in your web application](http://omaralzabir.com/prevent_denial_of_service__dos__attacks_in_your_web_application)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from your post you are worried that attackers will flood your authentication web service with requests. If the call to `Membership.ValidateUser` is expensive, this may lead to DOS.

First make sure that you have done everything *outside* the application layer to avoid DDOS. Google is your friend, maybe [this](http://www.linuxsecurity.com/content/view/121960/49/) will help.

Second, if the `Membership.ValidateUser` is expensive, try to make a two-step authentication process: Use a first request to inexpensively generate a [Proof-of-work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_work) token for the client and only accept calls to `Membership.ValidateUser` in the second request if the client has done some work.

Comment: As my client use javascript to create answer for Proof-of-work, it's open to attacker to copy the code and use same method to answer the service. so how it can work?

Comment: That is the beauty and purpose of proof-of-work: It is computationally expensive for the attacker to generate the proof-of-work and cheap for your server to check the proof. Let's say for the sake of an example it takes 250 ms to generate the proof of work and your server can process the proof in 5 ms. This will limit an attacker to 4 attacks per second while the server could check 200 requests/second. It doesn't matter of the attacker knows the algorithm, it still has to be executed to generate the proof of work.